# How to authenticate Spring Boot rest API having POST method using Azure AD

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory

In my spring boot rest api I am using a POST method. I am using Azure AD to authenticate api. When hitting an endpoint it is giving status as 200 OK but not doing the required POST operations. Even loggers are not getting printed from the controller `@PostMapping`

Can some help what needs to be fixed ...

---

In POM spring security and below dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Registered required properties in properties file.

```
azure.activedirectory.session-stateless
azure.activedirectory.tenant-id
azure.activedirectory.user-group.allowed-groups
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-id
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-secret
```

---

**NOTE**: There is no front end as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `@PostMapping` to authenticate for access token, you don't need to use azure-spring-boot-starter. You could refer the code sample based on [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow):

**Controller:**

```
@PostMapping("/access_token")
public AuthenticationResult authorizeToken(@RequestBody @Valid AuthorizationRequest authorizationCode) throws Exception {
    return tokenService.getAccessTokenFromAuthorizationCode(authorizationCode.getCode(), authorizationCode.getRedirectUri());
}
```

**Service:**

```
public AuthenticationResult getAccessTokenFromAuthorizationCode(String authorizationCode, String redirectUri) throws Exception {
   AuthorizationCode request = new AuthorizationCode(authorizationCode);
   try {
        return tokenGenerator.getAccessToken(request, redirectUri);
   } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        return throwException(throwable);
   }
}
```

**TokenGenerator function:**

```
public AuthenticationResult getAccessToken(
            AuthorizationCode authorizationCode, String currentUri)
            throws Throwable {
        String authCode = authorizationCode.getValue();
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId,
                clientSecret);
        AuthenticationContext context = null;
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        ExecutorService service = null;
        try {
            service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            context = new AuthenticationContext(authority + tenant + "/", true,
                    service);
            Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context
                    .acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(authCode, new URI(
                            currentUri), credential, resource, null);
            result = future.get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw e.getCause();
        } finally {
            service.shutdown();
        }

        if (result == null) {
            throw new ServiceUnavailableException(
                    "authentication result was null");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>4.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**application.properties**

```
security.oauth2.client.clientId=xxx
security.oauth2.client.clientSecret=xxx
security.oauth2.client.tenant=xxx
security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token
security.oauth2.client.userAuthorizationUri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/authorize
security.oauth2.client.authority=https://login.microsoftonline.com/
security.oauth2.client.resource=https://graph.windows.net/    // scope of API
security.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri=https://graph.windows.net/me?api-version=1.6    // call API
```

---

If you would like to authenticate in backend with Spring Boot Starter, please refer to this [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/spring/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-spring-boot-sample-active-directory-backend) based on [implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow).

Comment: What exact dependencies should I keep in POM and properties files ?

Comment: I add the pom and properties in my reply. You could refer to the whole [article](http://blog.xebia.in/index.php/2017/12/21/spring-security-and-oauth2-with-azure-active-directory/) using Spring Security and OAUTH2.